# can't get author from ctx when using author = ctx.author.mention

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever I try to do **author = ctx.author.mention** it gives me an error.

This is what my code looks like

```
@tree.command(name="getinfo", description="Gets a users info", guild=discord.Object(id=1045161049491505202))
async def getinfo(ctx, user:discord.Member):
    author = ctx.author.mention
    myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Account Info", description="Shows your **Server Join Date, Account Created Date, and Name**.", color=0x00ff00)
    myEmbed.add_field(name="**Name:**", value=user.display_name, inline=False)
    myEmbed.add_field(name="**Join Date:**", value=user.joined_at, inline=False)
    myEmbed.add_field(name="**Account Created Date:**", value=user.created_at, inline=False)
    myEmbed.add_field(name="**Top Role:**", value=user.top_role.mention, inline=False)
    myEmbed.set_author(name="General Frog")
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=myEmbed)
```

I don't know what else to try I tried changing ctx to message didn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\madri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1242, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\madri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 887, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\madri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 880, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'getinfo' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Comment: May you add or tell what error you got?

Comment: Sorry, I knew I forgot something. It now shows the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why you're using `ctx` as `discord.Interaction` but here's your issue; `discord.Interaction` does not have the attribute `author`, instead it has the attribute `user`. [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction.user)

```
@tree.command(name="getinfo", description="Gets a users info", guild=discord.Object(id=1045161049491505202))
async def getinfo(interaction: discord.Interaction, user:discord.Member):
    author = interaction.user.mention
    #rest of your code
```

I've switched `ctx` to `interaction` to not confuse you between the two, `discord.ext.commands.Context` is completely different from `discord.Interaction`.

Comment: I was able to get it working using what you showed me. I’m pretty new to discord.py so this helped a lot! Thank you